# rsync over local network using RSH returning "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: rsync

I've got rsync installed on my two machines on the same local network.  I'm trying to sync the /var/www/html/ folder between the two of them.

I've created a user on Machine A called "rsync"

And then I'm running this command on Machine B:

`rsync --rsh=rsh rsync@10.240.0.1:/var/www/html/ /var/www/html/`

...and getting this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

Why am I getting a "publickkey" related error when my command is asking to use rsh instead of ssh?  Since it's an internal network with no risk of eavesdropping, I wanted to use rsh to simplify things.

Can anyone tell me what step I'm missing to get this working properly?

(A few extra notes: I know I'll need other rsync flags but I've started with this to start.  Also I've tried rsync@an.incorrect.ip.address and got the error I was expecting with that.  So I know it's at least trying to connect to the right place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an actual `rsh` client installed?  or is your `/usr/bin/rsh` a symlink to `/usr/bin/ssh`? This is a fairly typical setup these days.

e.g. on Debian, `rsh` is, via the alternatives system, a symlink to `ssh`:

```
$ ls -lF /usr/bin/rsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 18  2018 /usr/bin/rsh -> /etc/alternatives/rsh*

$ ls -lF /etc/alternatives/rsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 May 18  2018 /etc/alternatives/rsh -> /usr/bin/ssh*

$ update-alternatives --display rsh
rsh - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/ssh
  link currently points to /usr/bin/ssh
  link rsh is /usr/bin/rsh
  slave rsh.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/rsh.1.gz
/usr/bin/ssh - priority 20
  slave rsh.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.gz
```

If I wanted an actual `rsh` client, I'd have to install the `rsh-client` package which would automatically update the alternatives links.

e.g. I just installed `rsh-client` on a VM to test:

```
# update-alternatives --display rsh
rsh - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/netkit-rsh
  link currently points to /usr/bin/netkit-rsh
  link rsh is /usr/bin/rsh
  slave rsh.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/rsh.1.gz
/usr/bin/netkit-rsh - priority 100
  slave rsh.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/netkit-rsh.1.gz
/usr/bin/ssh - priority 20
  slave rsh.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.gz
```

---

PS: `rsh` is obsolete, insecure garbage.  You should not be using it anyway, even on a local "totally-trusted-and-trustworthy" network.  Use `ssh` instead.  Just spend a few minutes creating an ssh key-pair (if you don't already have one) and installing the public key in the `~/.authorized_keys` file on the remote system.

Comment: This is really helpful. TBH, one of the reasons why I'm using `rsh` is because I'm really struggling with getting `ssh` set up.  I keep getting `Permission denied (publickey)` after going through all the key-gen steps I read online.  I suppose I should just submit a new question for this.  One thing I wonder, though, is whether you meant `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` instead.

Comment: yes, i did mean `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`....i checked the spelling of authorized and made sure it was American with a Z instead of English with an S, but didn't notice I'd used the wrong directory.

Comment: BTW, probably the easiest way to install a pub key on the remote host is to use `ssh-copy-id`.  e.g. `ssh-copy-id rsync@10.240.0.1`.  The remote host will ask for user rsync's password and if it's correct, will install the public key for that user (of course, this requires `PasswordAuthentication yes` to be in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` at least temporarily until the authorised keys are set up...but so does manually pasting the pubkey)

Comment: I finally figured out my problem.  I was following the directions for how to set up ssh keys just fine.  But no one ever told me that I had to do the same steps on both servers (generate a key pair on one server, save public key on the other... then repeat everything vice-versa)  Anyways, I'm very appreciative of your help you being a key player in me finally getting this whole thing sorted out!